# App Invoke is not allowed for this merchant in react native paytm integration

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, payment, paytm

I am trying to integrate paytm. but I am getting error = ' App Invoke is not allowed for this merchant in react native paytm integration.'

Comment: Did you find its solution? Please inform me as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

Please share the code of how you are calling the starttransaction method and please make sure that if you are testing on a staging environment you have a Paytm staging app that can be downloaded from GitHub

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of these:

1. Check if merchant id and merchant key is valid.
2. Website to be mentioned as "DEFAULT".
3. Request Body contains all the required key values.

Answer (score 0):

restrictAppInvoke: boolean

change boolean value from false to true